# Where can I put my Javascript schema definitions?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working with Meteor specifically, but I think this can be applied elsewhere.

The client sends an input to a method call on the server, which I check using a SimpleSchema variable:

```
ratingSchema = new SimpleSchema({
                ratingSafe : {
                    type : Number,
                    min : 1,
                    max : 5
                },
                ...
```

Rather than cluttering up my Meteor methods with these big definitions, can I put them in an external, unified file and use them from there?

Answer (score 0):

Make a folder for each collection, one file for the collection with schema, one for allow/deny and one for methods?